# How to extendLastCell() in itext7?

Tags: java, itext, itext7

In itext5 you can call setExtendLastRow(true); on a table. To have the last cell extend to the bottom of the page.

I am trying to have my itext7 table extend to bottom of page, even though it is just empty space.

I created a page border but it does not look as clean if the table's border spanned to the bottom of page.

Setting the height of the table does not work. The height property gets set but seems to not effect the actually height on the pdf page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the method providing this behavior has changed in iText7.

To extend the cells in the last row on every page, use

```
table.setExtendBottomRow(true);
```

To do the same for every page except the last one, use

```
table.setExtendBottomRowOnSplit(true);
```

Please note that this API will be available from release `7.0.2` on, which is not far away. This functionality is also already available in the latest `SNAPSHOT` version